# OpenJDK timezone issues: sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfoFile.getZoneIDs

Tags: java, ubuntu-12.04, time-zone, openjdk

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and recently installed the openjdk-7-jdk using apt-get.
For a while all seemed fine, but I realized one of my projects started to break with the following stack:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfoFile.getZoneIDs(ZoneInfoFile.java:790)
sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo.getAvailableIDs(ZoneInfo.java:601)
java.util.TimeZone.getAvailableIDs(TimeZone.java:580)
mpeg.psi.TOT.parseMJD(TOT.java:136)
```

Googli'n around I've found other people with similar issues, pointing out to a bug in the tzupdater.jar tool from Oracle. Should'n be my case, but I tried the fix suggested, checking and messing with the permissions of "lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 27 Set 20 08:59 /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/zi -> ../../../../../share/javazi" and running the tzupdater.
Somehow I fixed it, but some later update broke it again.

I decided to go radical then:

```
$> sudo apt-get purge openjdk-6-jre openjdk-6-jre-lib  openjdk-7-jre-headless openjdk-7-jre-lib openjdk-7-jre openjdk-6-jre-headless java-common
$> sudo apt-get install openjdk-6-jdk ant jdownloader java-common
$> sudo apt-get install tzdata-java
tzdata-java is already the newest version.
```

Still buggy :(

Now I'm out of ideas. The code that breaks this is: TimeZone.getAvailableIDs(-3 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
That is, I want to get GMT-3 to convert a set of numbers (hous, minute, day...) into a Date:

```
    gc.set(GregorianCalendar.YEAR, year);
    gc.set(GregorianCalendar.MONTH, month - 1);
```

Any tip on how to fix the Java TZ or how to bypass the issue on the java code?